# Linq - which query is faster?

Tags: c#, linq

I am wondering which one of these two is better to use:

1: `context.Threads.Where(thread => thread.Id == threadId).Select(thread => thread.Posts).(...)`

or

2: `context.Posts.Where(post=> post.thread.Id == threadId).Select().(...)`

Is there any difference between two?

Comment: Why don't you try to measure which one is faster for you? Also, the question in the title doesn't match the question in the body. So, what are you actually asking?

Comment: Well, in my opinion faster = better to use. :) And i cannot check which one is faster since i have empty database. Also, when i created this post i thought that maybe you guys will tell me that both of those expressions are doing the same thing, but as far as i see they are different, so i need to really look which one will be faster on my forum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to check also, in addition to how many threads and posts there are, what SQL is being generated by both queries, and how long they each take in SQL Profiler.

On a side note, I question both of your queries. I'm assuming that you're using Entity Framework (based on the other questions I've seen you ask), and so your Post class should have a ThreadID already on that table (based on the navigational property that I see here, you should have a ThreadID field on your Post table in your database). In which case the following query might be better suited for your needs:

```
context.Posts.Where(p => p.threadID == threadId);
```

By doing this you will remove any mention of the Threads table, which will mean that EF will not have to use any join statements to get the information that you're requesting. Since it's not going to include that Threads table, this should be the fastest way to go to get all posts from a single thread.

Comment: Oh well, i cannot do `(p => p.threadID == threadId)`, because in my model i have only naviagtional properties without their equivalent identificating properties (i don't really know how it is called). I don't use it because i am not using change tracking proxies either. So i am stuck with two solutions that i posted. :-/

Comment: This puzzles me. In order for your navigational property to work your physical database must have the threadID field on the table. I also don't know what having the threadID on the class has anything to do with change tracking proxies (if there's a connection, please share that with me), but you could always use AsNoTracking() on your queries, as described here: http://blog.staticvoid.co.nz/2012/4/2/entity_framework_and_asnotracking

Comment: Yes, physically in my db there are ID's that are pointing to a thread. But since i don't have declared this id in my post class (i have only navigational property - i.e. thread class itself), i cannot use post.threadId in my queries - EF just wont let me. I know it's stupid, but thats what it is. :/ And as for your question, heres the link that bothered me enough so i changed myu model so that it does not have threadId and no change tracking: http://coding.abel.nu/2012/03/ef-code-first-navigation-properties-and-foreign-keys/

Comment: Interesting posts. He does mention 2 things though that I think can come into play here: 1) He mentions that EF 5.0 fixes that SaveChanges() comparison problem, which means that you no longer have to have dynamic proxies. 2) His examples clearly still have the foreign key's id field on that table. He just makes sure to update the navigational property whenever the ID gets changed.

Comment: But that article advocates having both properties and keeping them synchornised.

Comment: @IronMan84: Yes. So i thought, that if i don't use proxies, then i won't use foreign keys in my classes either, so i won't need to update navigational properties, and therefor i will less likely have bugs in my code. But when i was thinking this way i thought that using `(p => p.threadID == threadId)` or `post=> post.thread.Id == threadId` is the same in words of effectiveness. Now, since i know it is not, i think i will add those foreign keys into my classes.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how many Threads and how many Posts there are.

Comment: Well, since there are threads, and single thread can have many posts, so there will be much more posts than threads. What now?